# Custom dynatree tooltip

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-dynatree

I use dynatree.I want customize tooltip for nodes like jquery tooltip and  when click on node then show tooltip.
How do it?

Comment: havea look at http://ddoong2.com/?page=259

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689990/dynatree-and-qtip2-no-hover-events-on-first-subnode

Comment: This example does not work.